# FusionCharts Pie showing wrong values

Tags: fusioncharts

The JSON below produces a FusionCharts Pie chart just fine, except the chart, when rendered, shows incorrect values. In this instance, the chart is showing:
Protein: 15.7%
Fat: 6.6%
Moisture: 77.7%
Why would it do this?

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
      var pieChart = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "pie2d",
        "renderAt": "detailPiechart",
        "width": "260",
        "height": "260",
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource": {
    "chart": {
        "paletteColors": "#18a4a4,#ffa365,#c0c0c0",
        "theme": "fint",
        "startingAngle": "325",
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "baseFontSize": "12",
        "pieRadius": "75",
        "labelFontSize": "12",
        "labelDistance": "1",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "showValues": "1",
        "animation": "0",
        "showLabels": "0",
        "use3DLighting": "1",
        "showShadow": "0",
        "enableSmartLabels": "0",
        "startingAngle": "0",
        "showPercentValues": "1",
        "showPercentInTooltip": "1",
        "decimals": "1",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
        "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
        "toolTipPadding": "5",
        "showHoverEffect": "1",
        "showLegend": "1",
        "legendBgColor": "#ffffff",
        "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
        "legendShadow": "0",
        "legendItemFontSize": "12",
        "legendItemFontColor": "#666666",
        "useDataPlotColorForLabels": "1"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "Protein",
            "value": "15.3"
        },
        {
            "label": "Fat",
            "value": "6.4"
        },
        {
            "label": "Moisture",
            "value": "75.8"
        }
    ]
   }
    });
    pieChart.render();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set showPercentValues attributes to 1

```
  {
  "chart": {
    "showPercentValues": "1",
    "showPercentInTooltip": "0"
  }
}
```

To know more about it please [refer](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#show-percent-values-and-actual-values)

[DemoJsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evzmw91k/)